# reading a list part of a class

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a class defined like this:

```
public static List<Email_to_Case> email_to_case { get; set; }
public class Email_to_Case
{
    public int caseId { get; set; }
    public string routingName { get; set; }
    public string emailAlias { get; set; }
    public List<string> emailExceptions { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public string priority { get; set; }
    public string origin { get; set; }
    public string recordType { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
    public string ownerType { get; set; }

    }
```

The `emailExceptions` List is populated from an XML Element in the config file like this:

```
List<string> eEx = new List<string>();
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pNode.Attribute("emailExceptions").Value))
    {
    string emailEx = pNode.Attribute("emailExceptions").Value;
    string[] s = emailEx.Split(';');
    foreach (string eExp in s)
        {
        eEx.Add(eExp);
        }
    }
ec.emailExceptions = eEx;
ec.ownerType = pNode.Element("owner").Attribute("type").Value;
... (cut for brevity)
email_to_case.Add(ec);
```

now I want to read through that list and for each one add to an (Exchange Web Services) `SearchFilterCollection`.

I tried to read it like this:

```
for (int iIdxExceptions = 0; common.email_to_case.emailExceptions.count-1 ; iIdxExceptions++)
{
// loop through the emailExceptions list in email2case.emailExceptions and for each one:
searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.Not(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.Subject, "FATS")));
}
```

but I am missing something fundamental as I have compile warnings, how should I do this to loop through the list which is part of the class?

**UPDATE:**
It's strange because in my calling form code, I can read it like this (BTW, **email_to_case** is defined in my *getConfig* like this: `email_to_case = new List<Email_to_Case>();`):

```
foreach (common.Email_to_Case e2c in common.email_to_case)
    {
    ... looping through ...

    for (int iEx = 0; iEx < e2c.emailExceptions.Count; iEx++)
        {
        ...
```

so, of course I can restrict the handling of the emails returned from Exchange Web Services, but I'd prefer to restrict the query in my `GetUnreadMailAll` method - just so I am not reading emails that should be excluded.

Comment: what kind of warning you get ?

Comment: Uh the second part of your for loop you don't compare your integer against the number...

Comment: @TimSchmelter: sorry, changed it to the web-services library name

Comment: Updated with more information.

Comment: @Tigran: it says that `common.email_to_case does not contain a definition for emailExceptions`

Comment: @Philip: you *probabbly* have double email_to_case type definition, where in one the list actually does not present.

Comment: @Tigran: they all have it... I have added more info at the bottom of my question